# Dynamic width of absolutely positioned div

Tags: css

So i'm having this:

```
  <style>
    div {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      width: 500px;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

  </style>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" style="float: left" value="leftButton">
    <input type="submit" style="float: right" value="rightButton">

  </div>
```

[an absolutely positioned button bar](http://jsbin.com/oxunuy/1/edit)

What I want: If the user resizes the window and makes it smaller than 500px, the buttons should get closer together instead of adding a scrollbar. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Have you tried setting the width using a percentage value instead?

Comment: @munnster79 yes - maybe I didn't go the last mile, but setting it blue eyed to whatever, 50%, is certainly not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:***

there is a solution!

```
width: 70%;
max-width: 500px;
```

This will make your bar adjust to the window width, but never exceed 500px. (optionally, add a min-width also)

Comment: thanks, the solution was the max-width together with min-width. See here: http://jsbin.com/oxunuy/7/edit e.g. set width to 100%, max-width: 500px, min-width: 200px. The question is browser compatibility

Comment: @toskan: please submit your solution as a seperate solution, instead of editing a similar existing one

Comment: @johannes the solution is max-width, so I think it is fair to accept a slightly corrected answer of him

Answer (score 2):

Use width specified as percentage.

```
width: 80%;
```

And if you need you can combine this with:

```
min-width: 30px;
```

To cover the case where user sizes too small to fit items in div.

If you want flexible button widths you can simply put them in a table row where the table cells are specified using percentages. Then they will size as user adjusts width. And here again you can combine with min-width and padding etc, to keep proper spacing. Eg.

```
<table style="width:90%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:10%;"></td>
        <td style="width:80%;"></td>
        <td style="width:10%;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```